# Android List is overwriting existing items instead of appending

Tags: android, listview

i'm fairly new to Android and got a problem.

When i'm trying to append a item to my list, it' overwriting the list instead of appending.

Here is my fragment call
Activity:

```
    FoodSearchFragmentContainer fragment = FoodSearchFragmentContainer.newInstance();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("query", query);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.frFoodSearch, new FoodSearchFragmentContainer());
    ft.commit();
```

My Dialog (fragment)

```
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.measurements_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

The list appender (fragment) FoodSearchFragmentContainer

```
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvIngredients);
    Ingredients i = new Ingredients();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    i.setName("test");
    ingredients.add(i);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The order is: i call the dialog, from the dialog the method in the activity and from there append the item to the list.

Also i cant access the bundle in the appender from my activity.

Gratefully
Lukas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i got the solution on my one now.

I Created everytime a new fragment, so they were overlapping.

Now i Create the Fragment in the OnCreate of the Activity and call a Method in the fragment to add a new item